# How to work on sqlite 3.7.3 installed in Mac OS 10.5

Tags: macos, operating-system, sqlite

I have installed sqlite 3.7.3 in my system which Mac OS 10.5.3. But I am unable to understand from where to start sqlite to create the database and tables in it.

Can anyone help me in this aspect.

I used http://snipplr.com/view/9360/installing-sqlite3-in-osx-leopard/ site to install sqlite in my Mac machine.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Please let me know if you need any other information as well.

Thanks in advance.

-Ankit

Answer (score 0):

sqlite will have been installed in /usr/local/bin (defined by the --prefix=/usr/local argument to configure)

This is on the default path so start this from the command line with

```
sqlite3
```

To be certain of this version use

```
/usr/local/bin/sqlite3
```